# Why do I get duplicated entries in my $PATH?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, environment-variables

I'm using Ubuntu 9.10 (karmic). And, my `~/.pam_environment` looks like the following.

```
PATH            DEFAULT=${PATH}:~/Adobe/Reader9/bin:~/texlive/2009/bin/x86_64-linux
GIT_EDITOR      DEFAULT=vim
MANPATH         DEFAULT=${MANPATH}:~/texlive/2009/texmf/doc/man
INFOPATH        DEFAULT=${INFOPATH}:~/texlive/2009/texmf/doc/info
```

But, `echo $PATH` returns me duplicated entries as the following.

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:~/Adobe/Reader9/bin:~/texlive/2009/bin/x86_64-linux:~/Adobe/Reader9/bin:~/texlive/2009/bin/x86_64-linux
```

I've tried replacing `DEFAULT` by `OVERRIDE` in my `~/.pam_environment` file. But, that didn't help.

Does any one know what's wrong with my `~/.pam_environment`?

Comment: Not directly related, but `~` won't work in there.  If you had set it from the shell it would have been expanded properly, but `pam_env` doesn't know how to expand it.  Use `${HOME}` instead.

Comment: See: https://superuser.com/questions/1216649/why-is-my-bash-profile-showing-duplicated-entries

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to stem from the fact that `pam_env` defaults to reading the user `~/.pam_environment` every time it is invoked.  A lot of login methods (cron, lightdm, lightdm-autologin, login, sshd and su on my machine) invoke `pam_env` twice: once to read the `/etc/environment` and `~/.pam_environment` files, and once to read the `/etc/default/locale` file.  In neither case is the `user_readenv` flag set, so `pam_env` reads, and acts on, your `~/.pam_environment` twice.

To fix this, go to your `/etc/pam.d` directory, and add the following to every line in which `pam_env` is invoked with the `envfile=/etc/default/locale` option:

```
user_readenv=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your `/etc/pam.d/` that `pam_env.so` isn't loaded twice somehow, such as both in `session` and in `auth`.

Comment: Which file should I examine in /etc/pam.d?

Comment: It looks like pam_env.so is actually loaded in both auth and session. See the output of "grep "pam_env *" in /etc/pam.d at http://www.filedropper.com/etc-pamd. What can I do about this duplication?

Comment: That URL doesn't exist (anymore?).  Please post the information here.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, exactly, but possibly useful to others who have duplication issues

---

Starting from the accept answer I received on from Stack Overflow: [How do I manipulate $PATH elements in shell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273909) I have developed a slightly large set of tools. Most of the credit here should go to [Jonathan Leffler](http://stackexchange.com/users/8423) who provided the model I used in writing these.

### Add without duplicating

```
# Insure that a path element exists by adding it to the end if it does not
#
#   $1 name of the shell variable to set (e.g. PATH)
#   $3 the path element that we want to insure exists
function insure_path () {
    local path=$1
    local list=$(eval echo '$'$path)
    local pat=$2

    checkstr=$(echo "$list" | tr ":" "\n" | grep -Fm 1 "$pat")
    if [ "$checkstr" ] 
    then
        true
    else
        export $path=$(echo $list:$pat | sed -e 's|\(:\):*|\1|g' -e 's|:$||' -e'
s|^:||')
    fi
}

# Insure that a path element exists by adding it to the front if it does not
#
#   $1 name of the shell variable to set (e.g. PATH)
#   $2 the path element that we want to insure exists
function insure_path_front () {
    local path=$1
    local list=$(eval echo '$'$path)
    local pat=$2

    checkstr=$(echo "$list" | tr ":" "\n" | grep -Fm 1 "$pat")
    if [ $checkstr ] 
    then
        true
    else
        export $path=$(echo $pat:$list | sed -e 's|\(:\):*|\1|g' -e 's|:$||' -e'
s|^:||')
    fi
}
```

### Remove existing duplicates

```
# Remove duplicates from a path. Preferes the ealiest instance of each
# duplicate because this preserves the semantics of the existing path
#
#   $1 name of the shell variable to set (e.g. PATH)
function unduplicate_path () {
    local path=$1
    local list=$(eval echo '$'$path)
    local split_list=$(echo "$list" | tr ":" " ")
    local tempp=""
    # Build the new version of $path from scrath
    for p in $split_list
    do
        insure_path_back tempp $p
    done
    # Now replace the existing version
    export $path=$tempp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround without messing with `/etc/pam.d` is using a temporary variable combination with `OVERRIDE` like this:

```
PATH                DEFAULT=${PATH} OVERRIDE=${PAM_ENV_PREV_PATH}
PAM_ENV_PREV_PATH   DEFAULT=${HOME}/.local/bin:${HOME}/.dotnet/tools:${PATH}
```

In the first round, `PAM_ENV_PREV_PATH` does not exist so `PATH` will be still the same value. In a second-round, `PAM_ENV_PREV_PATH` already exists by the first round so `PATH` will use this value instead.