# Why is my .bash_profile showing duplicated entries?

Tags: macos, bash, path

So I've been trying to do a cleanup of sorts on my mac OS .bash_profile (had a few issues with it), and now when I do `echo $PATH` on my Terminal I get the following:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home
:/usr/local/sbin
:/usr/local/sbin
:/usr/local/sbin
:/usr/local/bin
:/usr/bin
:/bin
:/usr/sbin
:/sbin
:/Users/herrmartell/bin
:/usr/local/bin/mysql/bin
:/Users/herrmartell/bin
:/usr/local/bin/mysql/bin
:/Users/herrmartell/bin
:/usr/local/bin/mysql/bin`

As you can see that's quite the number of duplicated entries. Which is odd, because this is what my .bash_profile looks like:

`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export MYSQL_PATH="/usr/local/bin/mysql"
export PATH=$PATH:$MYSQL_PATH/bin
export JAVA_HOME="/path/is/too/long/sorry"
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}:$PATH`

I've tried looking for another .bash_profile/.bash*/.profile file which might be overriding mine, but found none, also the changes I make on this one file are reflected on my `echo $PATH` results.

Found something related, but it's on Ubuntu and to be honest I got lost: [Why do I get duplicated entries in my $PATH?](https://superuser.com/questions/135730/why-do-i-get-duplicated-entries-in-my-path), and then something on Unix (lost me too, sorry): [Duplicate entries in $PATH a problem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14895/duplicate-entries-in-path-a-problem)

So far, it's not giving me problems, but I'd like to avoid actually getting them in the future.

What is wrong on my file then? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't already, try checking the following paths

```
cat ~/.bashrc
cat ~/.profile
cat ~/.bash_profile
cat /etc/bashrc
cat /etc/profile
cat /etc/bash_profile
```

You can also try

```
find ~ -type f -size -30k -exec grep -H herrmartell {} \;
find /etc -type f -size -30k -exec grep -H herrmartell {} \;
```

Comment: It looks to me like ~/.bash_profile is being run 3 times, so I'd look through the others and see if they're running it redundantly.

Comment: Tried all of those, I can only see .bash_profile (obviously), /etc/bashrc & /etc/profile. None is interfering with my .bash_profile (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0):

**2020 update**: In addition to paths associated with the (much maligned) `bash` shell, newer versions of MacOS use the `zsh` as the default shell and may be adding to (in that order):

```
/etc/zshenv    # Read for every shell
~/.zshenv      # Read for every shell except ones started with -f
/etc/zprofile  # Global config for login shells, read before zshrc
~/.zprofile    # User config for login shells
/etc/zshrc     # Global config for interactive shells
~/.zshrc       # User config for interactive shells
/etc/zlogin    # Global config for login shells, read after zshrc
~/.zlogin      # User config for login shells
~/.zlogout     # User config for login shells, read upon logout
/etc/zlogout   # Global config for login shells, read after user logout file
```

While previously the `bash` files were sourced conditionally (with the result that some users couldn't get their paths to be added), now all of these `zsh` files, if they exist, are sourced (with the results that some users find too many paths are added).

In addition, I have found paths in the following places:

```
private/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal
private/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal
private/etc/manpaths
private/etc/paths  # this one was the killer for me!
private/etc/paths~orig 
private/etc/paths.save # probably not sourced
private/etc/paths~save1 # probably not sourced
private/etc/manpaths.d/
private/etc/paths.d/
```

There are almost certainly more paths in other places, but for me `private/etc/paths` was the origin of much duplication. If anyone reading this finds more places, please ping me to add them!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post today, having hit a similar problem. I was able to find an alternative solution. Instead of hunting down where the replicate sourcing happens, check the value of $PATH before modifying it. For example, instead of

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin"
```

do this:

```
if ! [[ "$PATH" =~ ":$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin" ]]
then
    PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin"
fi    
export PATH
```