# How do I keep each PATH entry only once?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, environment-variables

I have just tried to add something to my `PATH` and realized it grew out of proportions because of duplicates:

```
C:\Users\user>setx Path "%Path%;C:\Python34"
WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
```

When I printed the `PATH` value, I realized it was filled with duplicate entries (`C:\Program Files\7-Zip` even got in 3 times), so there's no place for new data. Is there a way to get rid of the duplicates without manual editing, and preferably without installing third-party software? Any advice on how to avoid `PATH` duplicates is welcome as well.

I have found a [workaround](https://superuser.com/questions/387619/overcoming-the-1024-character-limit-with-setx) already, but still it feels sub-optimal to have duplicates in `PATH`.

Comment: See: https://superuser.com/questions/1216649/why-is-my-bash-profile-showing-duplicated-entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Is there a way to get rid of the duplicates without manual editing?

> Preferably without installing third-party software?

If you don't mind using a PowerShell script then you can remove duplicates using the following script from the [Microsoft Script Center](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/bb410849.aspx):

> **Script to check for duplicate paths in PATH environment variable**
>
> Sometimes repeated installation of software can add duplicate entries into the PATH environment variable. Since environment variable has a  there is a hard coded limit in the size of this variable, there are chances that you may it that limit over a period of time. This script checks the PATH environment variable and removes any duplicate path entries.
>
> ```
> $RegKey = ([Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine).OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment", $True) 
> $PathValue = $RegKey.GetValue("Path", $Null, "DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames") 
> Write-host "Original path :" + $PathValue  
> $PathValues = $PathValue.Split(";", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) 
> $IsDuplicate = $False 
> $NewValues = @() 
>   
> ForEach ($Value in $PathValues) 
> { 
>     if ($NewValues -notcontains $Value) 
>     { 
>         $NewValues += $Value 
>     } 
>     else 
>     { 
>         $IsDuplicate = $True 
>     } 
> } 
>   
> if ($IsDuplicate) 
> { 
>     $NewValue = $NewValues -join ";" 
>     $RegKey.SetValue("Path", $NewValue, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::ExpandString) 
>     Write-Host "Duplicate PATH entry found and new PATH built removing all duplicates. New Path :" + $NewValue 
> } 
> else 
> { 
>     Write-Host "No Duplicate PATH entries found. The PATH will remain the same." 
> } 
>   
> $RegKey.Close()
> ```

Source [How to check for duplicate paths in PATH environment variable](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-check-for-duplicate-5d9dd711)

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a python package called pathtub (I am the author of this package)

#### Installation

```
pip install pathtub
```

#### Usage

```
from pathtub import clean
# Default parameter values shown
clean(sort=True, remove_non_existent=True, remove_user_duplicates=True)
```

#### What does it do

- **Removes duplicates** and empty entries (`;;`) from the "User PATH" and "System PATH" (trailing backslash neglected when comparing two folders). Editing "System PATH" needs that python is executed with Admin rights.
- Removing from "User PATH" the entries that are in the "System PATH" (optional, enabled by default). Controlled with the `remove_user_duplicates`-parameter.
- Sorts PATH(s) alphabetically (optional, enabled by default). Controlled with the `sort` parameter.
- Removes folders from PATH(s) that do not exist on the filesystem (optional, enabled by default). Controlled with the `remove_non_existent` -parameter.

For more detailed description, please see the [documentation](https://github.com/np-8/pathtub) in GitHub.