# How to remove duplicate dirs from $PATH?

Tags: linux, bash, path

In some of my terminal windows I have duplicate entries in the `PATH` variable; something like this:

```
PATH=/a/b:/c/d:/a/b:/c/d:/e/f:/a/b
```

I guess the culprits are lines like this one in some of my scripts:

```
PATH=/a/b:$PATH
```

After sourcing this and that and this again `PATH` becomes very long. This the question:

Is there a `bash` command to cleanup `PATH` and similar env variables? It ought to be a `bash` script because one cannot execute a utility and expect it change the environment of the calling shell.

In the above example the cleaned up `PATH` should look like this:

```
PATH=/a/b:/c/d:/e/f
```

Comment: See [Duplicate entries in $PATH a problem?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/14895/57494)

Comment: See: https://superuser.com/questions/1216649/why-is-my-bash-profile-showing-duplicated-entries

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's better not to create the duplicates than to try and remove them afterwards. This is easily avoided with the technique I use in my `.bashrc` for adding my private `bin/` directory:

```
[ "${PATH#*$HOME/bin:}" == "$PATH" ] && export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

I did this at a time when I was making updates to `.bashrc` and I wanted to rerun it without restarting the shell.

If you want to add a directory to the end of `$PATH` you need to use a leading colon:

```
[ "${PATH#*:$HOME/bin}" == "$PATH" ] && export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

You can use parameter expansion to step through `PATH` and remove duplicates, but it would be a bit complex, and you would need to decide which position should be kept. Something along the lines of:-

```
OLDPATH="$PATH"; NEWPATH=""; colon=""
while [ "${OLDPATH#*:}" != "$OLDPATH" ]
do  entry="${OLDPATH%%:*}"; search=":${OLDPATH#*:}:"
    [ "${search#*:$entry:}" == "$search" ] && NEWPATH="$NEWPATH$colon$entry" && colon=:
    OLDPATH="${OLDPATH#*:}"
done
NEWPATH="$NEWPATH:$OLDPATH"
export PATH="$NEWPATH"
```

After having written this on the fly and now tested it, I should have removed most errors, and it should be an adequate guide to what you would need to do. It leaves the *last* occurrence of any duplicates, which is where they would be if you used my script to avoid duplicates in the first place. In a script it would of course need to be called with the `.`/`source` command.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution gives priority to entries that are further back in the list. However, if one needs an entry before others to override those paths, for instance /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin, this will break those priorities.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this simple Python 3 script:

```python
import os
    
# grab $PATH
path = os.environ['PATH'].split(':')

# normalize all paths
path = map(os.path.normpath, path)

# remove duplicates via a dictionary
clean = dict.fromkeys(path)

# combine back into one path
clean_path = ':'.join(clean.keys())

# dump to stdout
print(f"PATH={clean_path}")
```

I placed the script in `$HOME/scripts`, then added this line to the end of my `.bashrc`:

```
eval $(python3 $HOME/scripts/clean-path.py)
```

As of Python 3.7, a dictionary is guaranteed to preserve order, so `clean_path` will have directories in the same order as the original `PATH`.

Comment: This is nice, but won't putting the dirs into a map mix their order? Sometimes the order of PATH dirs matters: you can have executables with the same name in two dirs, for example if you want to replace a Unix tool (like maybe "find") with your own, so you put yours in a PATH dirs that comes before /usr/bin.

Comment: @Michael No, the `map()` function returns an iterable. The call to `map` iterates through `path`, applies the `normpath` function to each element, and appends the result to the return value. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Comment: Does this actually delete duplicates from the `PATH` or just print out the `PATH` without duplicates?

Comment: @mLstudent33 It prints the path with no duplicates. That's why I run `eval` at the end, to modify path outside of the Python process.

Comment: I'm using this approach after condensing it into a one-liner to add to `.bashrc`: `PATH="$(python -c "import os; print(':'.join(dict.fromkeys(map(os.path.normpath, os.environ['PATH'].split(':'))).keys()))")"`

Comment: @Michael I just realized 4 years later you were probably referring to the `dict`, not the `map` call. The answer is still "no" b/c Python 3.7+ dicts maintain their insertion order on iteration. 
@TheMechanic That's nice if it works for you. I typically don't do that b/c I always end up needing to change something later and I find that hard to read when I come back to it.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a bash sample.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [ -n "$PATH" ]; then
  old_PATH=$PATH:; PATH=
  while [ -n "$old_PATH" ]; do
    x=${old_PATH%%:*}       # the first remaining entry
    case $PATH: in
      *:"$x":*) ;;          # already there
      *) PATH=$PATH:$x;;    # not there yet
    esac
    old_PATH=${old_PATH#*:}
  done
  PATH=${PATH#:}
  unset old_PATH x
fi
echo ${PATH}
```

Answer (score 2):

With same doubt, I found [this question helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273909/how-do-i-manipulate-path-elements-in-shell-scripts).
So i can write this in bash

`TEST=$(echo -n $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | sort | uniq -c | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f3 | tr "\n" ":") && echo ${TEST%:}`

with output like this

`/bin:/home/root/gowork/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/pgsql-10/bin:/usr/sbin`

Comment: This  is short and works to remove dupes but it changes the order of the path elements , because of the `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty print version

```bash
if [[ -x /usr/bin/awk ]]; then
  export PATH="$(echo "$PATH" | /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN { RS=":"; } { sub(sprintf("%c$", 10), ""); if (A[$0]) {} else { A[$0]=1; printf(((NR==1) ?"" : ":") $0) }}')"
  echo $PATH
else
  echo "AWK is not located at /usr/bin/awk" # for the truly paranoid
fi
```

and here is a one-liner version

```bash
if [[ -x /usr/bin/awk ]]; then export PATH="$(echo "$PATH" | /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN { RS=":"; } { sub(sprintf("%c$", 10), ""); if (A[$0]) {} else { A[$0]=1; printf(((NR==1) ?"" : ":") $0) }}')" ; fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft technet addresses this problem with a [power shell script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-check-for-duplicate-5d9dd711). This script identify and remove duplicate entries from `PATH` variable.

It says:

> Sometimes repeated installation of software can add duplicate entries into the PATH environment variable. Since environment variable has a  there is a hard coded limit in the size of this variable, there are chances that you may it that limit over a period of time. This script checks the PATH environment variable and removes any duplicate path entries.

Comment: I know that powershell *can* be run on Linux (but NOBODY DOES).  Did you not look at the tags?